# Problem with install bundles ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "pg":
  In Gemfile:
    pg (= 0.18.4)

```
multilang-hstore (= 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
  pg (>= 0.0.1)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "responders":
  In Gemfile:
    responders (= 1.1.2)

```
devise (= 3.4.1) was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
  responders
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rubyzip":
  In Gemfile:
    axlsx (= 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      rubyzip (= 0.9.9)

```
zip-zip was resolved to 0.3, which depends on
  rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)
```

Comment: Be careful on what is updated in `Gemfile.lock`, especially if this is a production application, but `bundle update` could solve your problem here.

Comment: can you provide your Gemfile

Comment: Problem with old gems